# Are there any reuseable CSS stylesheets that provide some commonly used functionality?

Tags: css, stock, stylesheet

Examples might include:

- buttons (class="button" or similar)
- rounded boxes with headings (class="content-box" or similar)
- nice looking html tables (class="nice-table" or similar)
- customised html form fields

[example class names just to give an idea of expected behaviour]

Basically I just want some readymade CSS for common things.

My non-designer friend wants to get started creating a web app and I feel that ready made simple but attractive CSS classes would be a great help.

Comment: There are tons of pre-done CSS files ready to download if you Google for them...

Comment: And tons of adverts, useless sites, etc. Crap comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ones:

1. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ — css framework from creators of twitter, have wide range of common elements.
2. http://foundation.zurb.com/ — another framework with hight focus on prototyping.

Answer (score 2):

There is Skeleton: http://getskeleton.com. It has both JS and CSS patterns and is helpful for developing sites quickly, it's also mobile friendly.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI provides a nice framework for this, even if you don't use the javascript side of things.  You can reuse their CSS for whatever you need.  See here:

http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

Comment: jQuery UI stylesheet is not a total solution: There's no page layout styles or grid, no form styles - it just doesn't cut it as a framework, you need more (and a lot of it *relies* on javascript).

Comment: It does what the OP asked for.  You don't need a full layout framework to make some elements look pretty.  However I will upvote bootstrap as it's quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

YUI3. Yahoo! has created some of the best rules for web development.

1. Reset - level all browsers
2. Fonts - level all fonts
3. **Base - reapply some common styles**
4. Grids - best way to manage grid-like layouts

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/css/